# identify an event and recurrance of number

Tags: python

I have a text that I am trying to read, this looks something like

```
0;0;0
0;0;1# first time 1 appears-- |
0;1,2                         |one cycle for number one
0;1;2                         |
1;2;0 # last time 1 appears---|
2;3;4
0;0;0
0;1;2# second time 1 appears--|
0;1,2                         |second cycle for number one
0;1;2                         |
1;2;3 # last time 1 appears---|
2;3;4
...... so on
```

Say I have numbers in this file only between 1 to 4. I am supposed to neglect zero.

How can I calculate the number of cycles like this say for number 1 or for that matter every number using python?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, is there a reason why some text is separated by commas and some by semi colons?

Comment: Do you count occurrence of 1 no matter what column it appears in?

Comment: All numbers in line separated by semicolons. Yes we count occurance no matter in what column it appears.I am sorry I am searching for a logic/idea that can be used here to calculate the cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic strategy will go like this:

- set `cycle_count = 0`
- `read_until_contains_number()`
- `read_until_does_not_contain_number()`
- increment `cycle_count`
- repeat until no more input

This code will print `2` for the number `1`:

```
input= """0;0;0
0;0;1
0;1;2
0;1;2
1;2;0
2;3;4
0;0;0
0;1;2
0;1;2
0;1;2
1;2;3
2;3;4"""
lines = input.split('\n')

def count_cycles(lines, n):
    cycles = 0
    inside = False
    for line in lines:
        print line
        numbers = map(int, line.split(';'))
        if inside:
           if not n in numbers:
                # end of cycle
                cycles += 1
                inside = False
        else:
            print 'not inside'
            if n in numbers:
                # new cycle
                inside = True
    return cycles

print count_cycles(1)
```

Using an `if` like this is really bad form, since when the logic gets more complicated, this will break down.

Since you are probably going to do this to a file anyway, the basic strategy above could be implemented like this:

```
import StringIO
infile = StringIO.StringIO(input)

def count_cycles_in_file(f, n):
    cycles = 0
    while True:
        print 'in_count_cycles_in_file'
        try:
            read_until_start(f, n)
            read_until_end(f, n)
            cycles += 1
        except StopIteration:
            # EOF
            break
        print 'cycles:', cycles
    return cycles

def read_until_start(f, n):
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        numbers = map(int, line.split(';'))
        if n in numbers:
            return
        line = f.readline()
    # EOF
    raise StopIteration()

def read_until_end(f, n):
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        numbers = map(int, line.split(';'))
        if not n in numbers:
            return
        line = f.readline()
    # EOF
    raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: Thanks , I will use this idea.

Answer (score 2):

My code:

```
string = """0;0;0
0;0;1
0;1,2
0;1;2
1;2;0
2;3;4
0;0;0
0;1;2
0;1,2
0;1;2
1;2;3
2;3;4"""
import itertools
num = '1'
print sum(i for i,_ in itertools.groupby(string.split('\n'), lambda x: num in x and 1 or 0))
```